# Can not save any changes in Wordpress hosted on Windows Azure

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure

We are using Windows Azure platform to host wordpress along with mysql database. Three days ago, all in sudden, we can't save any changes to wordpress. The wordpress shows the changes are successfully made but none of them are taken effective. After googling the problem, it appears that the problem is with mysql permission on Windows Azure. I tried to reach Microsoft, but they direct me to here. I am wondering if anyone experience the same issue and have a solution to this. Thank you.

Comment: When you say, "save changes to WordPress," do you mean such things as editing and then updating a post?   Uploading a photo? Can you be more specific about what is not working?

Comment: Does your WordPress site include a cache plugin?  If so, try flushing the cache, or disabling the plugin.  Sometimes your audience doesn't see changes you made because the cache holds the previous versions.

Comment: The changes include the settings in wordpress admin portal. eg. I change my user profile or add a new user, then click to save the changes. The screen shows message saying it's saved or user created. But it does not actually save the change or add the user.

Comment: We're always met with messages claiming the changes were successful, but none actually are. This includes posting new blogs, editing those posts, changing options, deactivating plugins, anything. We hit submit, the page refreshes, and everything has reverted back.

Comment: Combing through the php_errors.log, I found countless errors such as these occuring in the last 3-4 days: 
[29-Jan-2013 17:57:09 UTC] WordPress database error INSERT,UPDATE command denied to user 'username'at symbol'ip address' for table 'wp_options' for query INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES (...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from MSDN forum. The problem with mysql db on azure is that the db is actually hosted at cleardb. azure provision the mysql db as a service but the initial space is 20MB only. It's earsily running out space. I have to go to cleardb dot com to register a payable account and link to azure. Then increase the space. It worked right away.

MSFT currently has very limited support for WindowsAzure. I am not satisfied. But I am glad I can find the answer from tech forum eventually.